# Ocultar Tab en primereact

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un componente  de [primereact](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/tabview).

```
<TabView >
    <TabPanel header="Panel 1">
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel header="Panel 2">
    </TabPanel>
</TabView>
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar / ocultar una pestaña según un valor concreto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tener una lista de pestañas a mostrar e ir modificando la lista cuando te convenga:

```
const tabs = [1, 2]; //Esta lista es la que tienes que generar mirando condiciones

const listItems = tabs.map((number) =>
  <TabPanel header="Panel {number}"></TabPanel>
);
```

y luego hacer algo como

```
return (<TabView > {listItems} </TabView>);
```